# Index Writer in Append mode causing open deleted files in unix

Tags: java, lucene

I recently upgraded our search application from Lucene 2.4 to Lucene 3.6.2
We run a job that pulls updates from database every 4 hours and updates the existing Lucene Index.

Code used for creating Index Writer -:

```
indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dirPath, new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36,
                    analyzer).setOpenMode(OpenMode.APPEND));
```

Post successfully adding documents to existing index we do following on Index Writer.

```
indexWriter.commit();
indexWriter.deleteUnusedFiles();
indexWriter.close();
```

Post above steps we do following on IndexSearcher

```
this.indexSrchr.getIndexReader().decRef();
this.indexSrchr.close();
// Create a new Index Searcher to point to updated index.
this.indexSrchr = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(dir));
```

The Index Writer when opened in CREATE mode works perfectly fine but with APPEND mode it
causes Open deleted files to be added every time i try the update on index.

Unix Command Used -:

```
lsof -u user | grep delete.
```

Can someone please help me if there is an issue at lucene level itself or we are doing something wrong?

---

I was able to solve the issue as somewhere in the code we were not explicitly doing a decrease reference on the indexReader

`this.indexSrchr.getIndexReader().decRef()`

But can someone help me understand why

`this.indexSrchr.close()`

does not close the underlying index reader of the Index Searcher ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `CREATE` you create a new index all the time and that's why you don't experience the issue. When you are `APPEND`ing to the index it recognizes the previous one of the files already indexed as deleted.

If you don't close the `IndexReader` after you read through the dir the files are still being accessed so they can't be deleted by `deleteUnusedFiles`.